# Can Azure Spatial Anchors work with multiple floors in a building?

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I am trying to consider the capabilities & limitations of Azure Spatial Anchors, I tried using the sample to test in my own building, but it was not working properly, but I suspect it may be an issue with the way I was using it.

Just wanted to check if ASA actually works with multiple anchors on different floors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to place anchors in different floor. The anchors are unique by visual features if your floors are visually distinguishable you should see no problems.

Can you elaborate what you mean by it not working?

Comment: I see! I was using the nearby demo sample, but I think I did not set it up correctly because my floors were pretty identical, but thank you for the answer!